# How to show bootstrap modal dialog in vue js?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have been trying to show modal dialog using bootstrap and vue js. I want to show dialog once user successfully registers.

```
<div>
....
    <div class="modal fade" v-if="isEnabled">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
....
</div>
```

But not able to display the dialog. Can anybody help me to do this?

Comment: You're probably better off using [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/) which is designed specifically for vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal component is managed by jQuery, you have to use jquery to open your modal.

I need you Vue code too help you much, if it's an ajax request to register user, wait the success callback to make a

```
$('#modal').modal('show')
```

If it's a synchronous process, call you modal in the mounted method of you Vue instance.

Answer (score -1):

for eg:

if you want to show modal box on click button then use

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

and if you want to open model box after any process is finished then use

```
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

"#myModal" is ID of the modal box you want to show.

## more info https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp